# Is there a way to select an array object relevant to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

So let's say I have an array with a name of test. If I assign it like this: `var test = [1, 2, 3, 4];`
Is there a way to choose the number 2 by saying which number is below 3?

Sorry if I didn't explain it good enough, if theres a part you didn't understand tell me and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: is the array always ordered?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a way to choose the number 2 by saying which number is below 3?"

Comment: I mean is there a way to make the program tell us which number is below 3 in the array order.

Comment: So, for `[1, 4, 3, 2]` you expect the result to be `4`?

Comment: I think OP is talking about the value, not index

Comment: I'm talking about the index, I'm waiting to accept @NullDev 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the index of `3` and then just count one index down from there:

```js
var test = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(
    test[test.indexOf(3) - 1]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and check if the number is less than 3 and is biggest in the array.

```js
var test = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var output = test[0];
test.forEach(function (num) {
  if (num < 3 && output < num) {
    output = num;
  }
})

console.log(output);
```